Dedicated Server + Proxmox + OPNSense + IPv6 Support for VMs in LAN
I am struggling setting up a working IPv6 network for VMs connected at OPNsense LAN interface.
The provider (Hetzner) has given me a /64 IPv6 network:  2a01:4f8::::/64
Somehow I am able to create a working IPv6 network for Proxmox itself and OPNsense with below configurations:
Proxmox (Debian) /etc/network/interfaces:
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface lo inet6 loopback

auto enp0s31f6
iface enp0s31f6 inet static
        address 94.130.***.***/26
        gateway 94.130.***.***
        up route add -net 94.130.***.*** netmask 255.255.255.192 gw 94.130.***.*** dev enp0s31f6
       # route 94.130.***.***/26 via 94.130.***.***

iface enp0s31f6 inet6 static
        address 2a01:4f8:****:****:aaaa::11/128
        gateway fe80::1

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
        address 10.10.10.1/24
        bridge-ports none
        bridge-stp off
        bridge-fd 0
        post-up echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward post-up   iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s '10.10.10.0/24' -o enp0s31f6 -j MASQUERADE 
        post-down iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s '10.10.10.0/24' -o enp0s31f6 -j MASQUERADE 
        post-up   iptables -t raw -I PREROUTING -i fwbr+ -j CT --zone 1 
        post-down iptables -t raw -D PREROUTING -i fwbr+ -j CT --zone 1

iface vmbr0 inet6 static
        address 2a01:4f8:****:****:aaaa::1336/127
        up ip route add 2a01:4f8:****:****::/64 via 2a01:4f8:****:****:abcd::1337

auto vmbr1
iface vmbr1 inet manual
        bridge-ports none
        bridge-stp off
        bridge-fd 0

iface vmbr1 inet6 manual

OK, now the hard part:
Ping from Proxmox to OPNSense works OK
Ping from OPNSense to Proxmox works OK
Ping from Proxmox to google: ping6 google.com is OK
Ping from OPNSense to google: ping6 google.com is OK
Ping from VM to OPNSense (2a01:4f8:::aaaa::1337) works OK
Ping from VM to Gateway (2a01:4f8:::aaaa::1336) FAILS
Ping from VMs to Google (ping6 google.com) FAILS
In OPNSense, at  IPv6 Configuration Type, choosed Static IPv6 with the following values: 2a01:4f8:::0172:0016:0:0001/125
In OPNSense, at ISC DHCPv6: [LAN], enabled the services and added to Range from: 2a01:4f8:::172:16:0:1 -> to 2a01:4f8:::172:16:0:7
In OPNSense, at Router Advertisements: [LAN], choosed Managed and DNS Servers as following:
2001:4860:4860::8888
2001:4860:4860::4444
When trying to boot a VM e.g. in my case 1 Windows and 1 Ubuntu, they are getting an IPv6 address from DHCPv6 from OPNSense but cannot access or resolve the IPv6 adresses.
Ping shows current values:
ping6 google.com
PING google.com(fra24s05-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4001:828::200e)) 56 data bytes
--- google.com ping statistics ---
33 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 32747ms

What I am missing? Really getting tired for days with trying different configurations, but doesn't work. If anybody can assist I really appreciate that a looooot.
